# Using BETWEEN in a DataTable.Select

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, select, datatable

I thought this would be simple but obviously not!

Basically, I have a date and want to do a 'between' on two date columns like this:

```
myDataTable.Select(myDate & " between (StartDate and EndDate)")
```

Where StartDate and EndDate are date columns that do exist in the DataTable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just use ***>=*** and ***<=***

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
dt.Columns.Add("StartDate")
dt.Columns.Add("EndDate")
Dim row1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
row1("StartDate") = New DateTime(2009, 1, 1)
row1("EndDate") = New DateTime(2009, 1, 31)
dt.Rows.Add(row1)

Dim myDate As New DateTime(2008, 12, 15)
Dim rows As DataRow() = dt.[Select]([String].Format("#{0}# >= StartDate AND #{0}# <= EndDate", myDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")))
```

Comment: I use myDate.toString("O") for a general date format that complies with ISO Standards and dont rely on current culture. VB will convert that back to a date when executing the select - and with "dd MM yyyy" I am always unsure when it converts 02 03 2000 to march 2nd and when to Feb 3rd

Answer (score 5):

The `DataTable.Select` method doesn't support the `BETWEEN` operation. This operation is specific to a database engine. Remember that the `DataTable` is an in-memory construct and doesn't necessarily support all the features of a database server.

The `DataTable.Select` method supports the same filter expression syntax as [`DataColumn.Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx). You can try the following expression to achieve the same thing (note I haven't tested this!):

```
myDataTable.Select("#" + myDate + "# >= StartDate AND EndDate <= #" + myDate + "#");
```

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull, first you have to write column name then the condition and at the end it goes the variable:

```
myDataTable.Select( **StartDate** =< "#" + myDate + "# AND **EndDate** <= #" + myDate + "#");
```